# Analytic solution to given integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is there an analytic solution to the following integral:

$\int_B^\infty \mathrm{d}\Lambda \frac{ e^{\frac{\pi  (\Lambda +1)}{c}}}{ \left(e^{\frac{2 \pi  \Lambda }{c}}+e^{\frac{2 \pi }{c}}\right)}  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \Lambda -2}{c}\right)$

where $c\in \mathbb{R^+}$.

Mathematica shows that the integral converges even for any random value of $B\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prove that this integral converges or to find an analytic formula for the integral?

Comment: I would like to find the analytic solution for the integral.

Comment: By analytic solution you mean not only to show that it converges, but also to find what it converges to, correct? It is pretty simple to show that it converges. Is there any specific reason to think that this would converge to something that can be expressed in closed form? Where does this integral come from?

Comment: That's correct. The integral came in a physics problem; while calculating the ground state energy of a lattice model using the Bethe Ansatz method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{e^{\frac{\pi  (x+1)}{c}} }{e^{\frac{2 \pi  x}{c}}+e^{\frac{2 \pi }{c}}}\,\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x-2}{c}\right)\,dx$$
$$x=1+\frac{c }{2}t\implies I=\frac{c}{4} \int \tan ^{-1}(t)\,\, \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}t\right)\, dt=\frac c{2\pi}\int \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y}{\pi }\right) \text{sech}(y)\,dy $$ I do not see how to have a closed form but this integral looks like a distribution function.

However, we can write
$$I=\frac c \pi \int \frac {\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y}{\pi }\right) }   {e^y+e^{-y} }\,dy=\frac c \pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int e^{-(2 n+1) y} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y}{\pi }\right) \,dy$$

$$J_n= \int_b^\infty e^{-(2 n+1) y} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y}{\pi }\right) \,dy$$
$$J_n=\frac {(-1)^n } {2(2n+1) }\Bigg[\text{Ei}\left(\frac{i}{2}  (2 n+1) (2 i
   b-\pi)\right)+\text{Ei}\left(\frac{i}{2}  (2 n+1) (2 i b+\pi )\right)+2 (-1)^n
   e^{-(2 n+1) b} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 b}{\pi }\right)  \Bigg]$$
$$K_n=\int_0^\infty (-1)^n
   e^{-(2 n+1) y} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y}{\pi }\right)\,dy=\frac 1{2n+1}\text{Ci}\left(  (2 n+1)\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$